# Limiting asynchronous requests without blocking

Tags: c#, multithreading, http, asynchronous

i am after some advice/strategy on limiting http requests when consuming multiple web services. I feel i could do this if the requests were happening synchronously, but they are asynchronous and think i should try to perform the limit logic in a way that i wont block.

Due to the web app consuming multiple web services there will be different limits for different requests. I was thinking something like this, but aren't sure how to proceed in a no blocking manner:

request method:

```
public static Task<string> AsyncRequest(string url, enum webService)
{
    using(LimitingClass limiter = new LimitingClass(webService))
    {
       //Perform async request
    }
}
```

In the LimitingClass it will have logic like checking the last request for the given webservice, if it violates the limit then it will wait a certain amount of time. But in the mean time if another request comes in to a different webservice then i dont want that request to be blocked while the LimitingClass is waiting. Is there anything fundamentally  wrong with the above approach? Should i open up a new thread with each LimitingClass instance?

Some pseudo code would be great if possible.

Many Thanks

UPDATE:

This is a simplified version of my current request method:

```
public static Task<string> MakeAsyncRequest(string url, string contentType)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = //set up my request

    Task<WebResponse> task = Task.Factory.FromAsync(
        request.BeginGetResponse,
        asyncResult => request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult),
        (object)null);

    return task.ContinueWith(t => ReadCallback(t.Result));
}
```

I just want to wrap this in a using to check the limits and which doesnt block other requests.

Comment: Sounds like you want a semaphore per web service.

Comment: Alternatively, you could simply cache responses for your wait period, and then only rerequest service resources once the cache has expired.

Comment: I do cache the common requests, but others requests aren't cached due to them being being too unique/rare.

Comment: Well, how is your code functioning? It sounds like this is in a multithreaded scenario anyways, or is only one thread ever requesting resources?

Comment: @Tejs Updated with my request method

Comment: That's doesnt explain the answer though; are multiple threads invoking `MakeAsyncRequest`, or just one thread? If it's multiple threads, then there is no problem in having a single thread block for a specified amount of time.

Comment: Its web app, IIS opens up a thread for each user right? so this class could have multiple threads invoking it. You will have to bare with me im new to aysnchronous and multithread programming.

Comment: In that case, you don't want to be blocking the threads at all. If it's not time for a new request of your service, then you should return a cached response or indicate some dummy value back to the user.

Comment: I currently return a cached response if applicable. Not following the rest of your comment. Shouldnt I just open up a new thread for the limiterclass? The fromsync method opens up née threads for multiple requests as it needs right I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So how are you limiting an access to resource without blocking ?

I think you need to look at [Semaphores](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim.aspx) - they allow to limits the number of threads that can access a resource or pool of resources concurrently.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on using semaphores?

Comment: Hmm, it's what I said above. You can allow say 5 threads to access your resource; 6th will have t wait until one of the first 5 is done. It is still a blocking solution, but it doesn't limit access to 1 thread. Btw, you're accessing a web service, why do you want to limit the number of synchronous requests to it ? Sounds wrong to me.

Comment: Im not limiting the number of synchronous requests, i am simply conforming to the web service rules, IE 2 calls max a second etc, whilst allowing other requests to take place simultaneously.

Comment: Ok.. So why not just create a static wrapper around that web service, which will check the time from the last request ? If this given second already had 2 requests - return some message. Interesting how you'll calculate the rate - request counter, which will reset every second, or 0.5 second period between requests ?

Comment: The limiting class will be the wrapper round the web service which works out the limit for each web service but my problem is if the limiting class is waiting how do I allow other requests to different web services to pass through?

Comment: I pass in a enum which represents a webservice and i can work out the request limit from that. Its just that if the request has violated the limit then i want to pause or sleep but just without blocking the thread.

Comment: Ah, so you're on a client side. Create a queue of requests, and put requests there. Then have another thread that will pick an item from a queue every .5 seconds.  However, if at some point you will have a flood of requests, your queue will get long - so it may or may not work for you.